# webpack-dev-server@1.16.5 hot reload NOT working properly?

Tags: webpack-dev-server

starting webpack-dev-server --hot

i see the code run to client/index.js:

```
    log("info", "[WDS] App hot update...");
    console.log('window object',currentHash); //printed
    window.postMessage("webpackHotUpdate" + currentHash, "*");
```

but not triggering below dev-server code:

```
    hotEmitter.on("webpackHotUpdate", function(currentHash) {
    console.log('inside weboackHotUpdate'); //not printed
    lastHash = currentHash;
    console.log('module.hot.status|'+ module.hot.status());
    if(!upToDate() && module.hot.status() === "idle") {
        log("info", "[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...");
        check();
    }
});
```

this affect the automatic refresh of window after hotmodulereplacement,

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

i temporarily solved the window reload issue by add location.reload() after the window.postMessage, not sure how the post message "webpackHotUpdate" get handled if not from -hotEmitter.on("webpackHotUpdate",...- method